# Kusto Query Language: set column name of summarize by evaluated expression

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

Me again asking another Kusto related question (I really wish there would be a thorough video tutorial on this somewhere).

I have a `summarize` statement, that produces two columns for y axis and one for x axis.
Now i want to relabel the columns for x axis to show a string, that i also got from the database and already put into a variable with `let`.

This basically looks like this:

```
let android_col = strcat("Android: ", toscalar(customEvents
| where application_Version contains secondLatestVersionAndroid));
let iOS_col = strcat("iOS: ", toscalar(customEvents
| where application_Version contains secondLatestVersionIOS));

... some Kusto magic ...

| summarize
    Android = 100 - (round((countif(hasUnhandledErrorAndroid == 1 ) * 100.0 ) / countif(isAndroid == 1), 2)),
    iOS = 100 - (round((countif(hasUnhandledErroriOS == 1) * 100.0 ) / countif(isIOS == 1), 2))
    by Time
|render timechart with (ytitle="crashfree users in %", xtitle="date", legend=visible )
```

Now i want to have the summarize display not Android and iOS, but the value of android_col and iOS_col.

Is that possible?

Best regards
Maverick

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's suggested to have predefined column names, otherwise various features don't work. For example, IntelliSense won't know the names of the columns, as they would be determined at run time only. Also, if you create a function that returns a dynamic schema, you won't be able to run this function from other clusters.

However, if you do want to change column names, you definitely have a way to do it by using various plugins. For example, [bag_unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin), [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) and others.

As for courses on Kusto, there are actually several excellent courses on Pluralsight (all are free):

- [How to start with Microsoft Azure Data Explorer](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-azure-data-explorer-starting)
- [Basic KQL](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch)
- [Azure Data Explorer – Advanced KQL](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/microsoft-azure-data-explorer-advanced-query-capabilities)

Comment: tyvm for the courses. will start asap with them to get a better understanding of what Kusto is capable of and what are my options when using it.
For the change of the column name. i was afraid it would be like this and i understand the reasons, but in my case those reasons all do not apply, so i will try one of the plugins

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the "toscalar" in this query looks wrong, it seems to me that you should use the "extend" operator with the same logic to create the additional columns.